# Can't change the position of the OverviewMapControl

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to change the position of the overviewMapControl but I can't.

```
overviewMapControl: true,
overviewMapControlOptions: {
opened: true,
position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT   
}
```

http://www.fuerteventura-maps.com/overview.html
Am I doing the wrong thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, you can't position this control. The only option is opened.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#OverviewMapControlOptions

Comment: Ah. Thanks. Hmm bit disappointing. Will have to work around it I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I looked around a lot as well and the only way I could find to do this is to create a new custom control div with a small google map instance inside it. It is true and disappointing that the only option for the built in feature is 'opened'.

Working example: http://rumsey.mapranksearch.com/

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomExample

Comment: Hmm... http://rumsey.mapranksearch.com/ shows a map with the OverviewMapControl in the bottom right corner, so in the default position? So I don't see how it could be a working example of _changing_ the position of it?